# Matching company names from 2 columns in R

Tags: r

I downloaded a list of public companies from SEC Edgar (http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/full-index/).

I'm trying to find matches between companies in a different list, which could have variations in case and punctuation. Any suggestions for matching company names between two columns?

Here's an example:

```
> df.a 
   Company 
"Flowers David"
"Danone Inc."

> df.b
Company
"1 800 FLOWERS COM INC"
"FLOWERS DAVID J A"
"FLOWERS FOODS INC"
```

I'm trying to find matches between the two in a way that makes sense. So only "FLOWERS DAVID J A" would get matched.

Comment: In a way "that makes sense" isn't quite precise enough to ask a computer to do. Do you have a specific programming question? If this is more theoretical, you might consider moving your post to [cs.se] or [stats.se].

Comment: There are functions that will help (`grep` with `ignore.case`, `%in%`, regex, etc.), but you're asking a subjective question.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the issues with my question. @MrFlick,you're correct in that this is more theoretical. What I'd like to know is how to find the greatest number of correct matches and figured that some people will have experience with matching company names. How can I move it to CS or CV?

Comment: Delete here and re-post there. Just make sure not to cross-post to a bunch of sites; that's considered bad form.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of possibilities:

The `agrep` function will do approximate matching, you could loop through the 1st list using each term as the "pattern" to look for approximate matches in the 2nd list.  You may want to preprocess the lists a little first, remove all punctuation, convert all letters to lower case, etc.  The `adist` function works with it to show the distances.  There is more information on the help page

There are tools that compute the similarity or dissimilarity between strings, the `dissimilarity` function in the tm package is one.  You could use that to measure the dissimilarities between your 2 vectors, then look for the least dissimilar pairs.